# Prevent scaling in subroutines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want my routine to draw lengths independent of the main program scale.  E.g. in sample below, I defined routine `\test` which writes the line between two points, but lengthen the line on one side by 30pt and also draw 30pt line perpendicular to that line.

Curiously, `shorten` routine does not scale with tikzpicture scale, but routine for perpendicular line does.  Why is that so and how to prevent scaling of routine for perpendicular line?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\test}[2]{%
\draw[shorten <=-30pt] #1 -- #2 node[pos=-0.1] {30pt};
\draw #1 -- ($#1!30pt!-90:#2$) node[midway] {30pt};
\draw[red] #1 -- #2;}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,scale=10]
\draw[white] (-0.8,-0.8) rectangle (1,1);
\test{(0,0)}{(1,1)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,scale=3]
\draw[white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\test{(0,0)}{(1,1)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,scale=1]
\draw[white] (-1.8,-1.8) rectangle (1,1);
\test{(0,0)}{(1,1)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not strange, it is by design. Only coordinates are scaled (and some particular lengths, like `outer sep` for backward compatibility). For example `inner sep` is not scaled, `line width` neither. Shorten is supposed to be in 'accordance' with the `line width`, so not scaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scaling is done for coordinates, but (typically) not for node contents (can be changed) and length values like `line width` et.al. This gives the differences between `shorten` and the coordinate computations.

You could use the following to prevent scaling:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\test}[2]{%
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\mylength{30pt/\myscale}%
\draw ($#1!-\mylength!#2$) -- #1 node[midway] {30pt};
\draw #1 -- ($#1!\mylength!-90:#2$) node[midway] {30pt};
\draw[red] #1 -- #2;}

\tikzset{myscale/.code={\edef\myscale{#1}\tikzset{scale=#1}}}
\def\myscale{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,myscale=10]
\draw[white] (-0.8,-0.8) rectangle (1,1);
\test{(0,0)}{(1,1)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,myscale=3]
\draw[white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\test{(0,0)}{(1,1)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,myscale=1]
\draw[white] (-1.8,-1.8) rectangle (1,1);
\test{(0,0)}{(1,1)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The other way around would be allow scaling for both lines (that is easier):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\test}[2]{%
\draw ($#1!-30pt!#2$) -- #1 node[midway] {30pt};
\draw #1 -- ($#1!30pt!-90:#2$) node[midway] {30pt};
\draw[red] #1 -- #2;}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,scale=10]
\draw[white] (-0.8,-0.8) rectangle (1,1);
\test{(0,0)}{(1,1)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,scale=3]
\draw[white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\test{(0,0)}{(1,1)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,scale=1]
\draw[white] (-1.8,-1.8) rectangle (1,1);
\test{(0,0)}{(1,1)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]